# sqlalchemy .commit() extremely slow

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm experiencing a unusually slow commit() time with one of my tables. more than 2 min per commit(). I have no idea why and have searched for an answer but could find one. Right before commiting it I commit different information and that takes about 4 second with the same ammount of data (4k entries +-)

this is the table:

```
class BranchPrice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'branch_price'

    branch_price_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    chain_id = Column(db.ForeignKey('chain.id'))
    item_code = Column(db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    branch_id = Column(db.ForeignKey('branch.id'))
    price = Column(DECIMAL)
    update_date = Column(Text)
```

furthermore I add roughly 4K entries per commit.
I run this code in a loop followed by a commit():

```
branch_price = BranchPrice(chain_id=self.chain_id, branch_id=branch_id,item_code=item_code, price=price, update_date=update_date)

db.session.add(branch_price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move from individual inserts to bulk inserts. SQLAlchemy has [benchmarking scripts](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/performance/bulk_inserts.html) for different types of bulk operations.

In any case, have a look at inserting not the `BranchPrice` object, but a list of dictionaries instead, through [`BranchPrice.__table__.insert()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values) or [`session.bulk_insert_mappings`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=bulk_insert_mappings#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings).

If you do want to use `BranchPrice` objects, maybe because of some logic in the initialisation step, [`session.bulk_save_objects`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=bulk_insert_mappings#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects) is the fastest.